# ASP CORE JSON OBJECT NULL or COUNT 0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json, asp.net-core

I'm trying to send a list of values from View to Controller. I tried a lot of solutions from the Internet but haven't succeeded.

My View HTML Table list of Data send to controller via JSON but the list is empty even when I use `JSON.stringify`

Heres my code

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

     $("body").on("click", "#btnSave", function () {

        //Loop through the Table rows and build a JSON array.
        var customers = new Array();
        $("#tblCustomers TBODY TR").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var customer = {};
            //skill.skill_name = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
            customer.CNIC = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
            customers.push(customer);
        });

        console.log(customers);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(customers));

        //Send the JSON array to Controller using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            //traditional: true,
            url: "/Admin/Reconcile/Customers",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: JSON.stringify(customers),
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + " record(s) inserted.");
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });

</script>
```

Controller Action:

```
public JsonResult Customers(List<String> customers) 
{

}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(JSON.stringify(customers));` produce?

Comment: this [{"CNIC":"----"},{"CNIC":"----"},{"CNIC":"EK6184014"}]

Comment: i have the model Templist model which have CNIC List<TempList> customers) but the count is still 0

Comment: That is not a list of strings. but a list of objects with a string property called: CNIC

Comment: remove `contentType` and change to `data:customers` - you're not accepting a *string* so don't send one.

Comment: *or* change your action to accept a string:  `public JsonResult Customers(string customers) {` and then parse it in the action.

Comment: i remove contentType and change data: customers but still :( zero same issue any other way i can post data of table one by one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly,you need to create a model like this:

```
public class Customer {
        public string CNIC { get; set; }
    }
```

Then since you pass json type data in ajax,you need to use `[FromBody]` in action:

```
public JsonResult Customers([FromBody]List<Customer> customers)
        {
            
        }
```

Comment: thanks it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You are sending an array of objects, so for the model binder to work you should accept a List of SomeModel, where SomeModel should have a property CNIC. Check the documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api on how objects are binded.

So you are sending this:

```
[
  {
     "CNIC":"somevalue",
     "CNIC":"somevalue"
  }
]
```

And you are trying to bind it to a List of string and it will not happen. Try binding it with List of SomeModel:

```
public class SomeModel
{
    public string CNIC { get; set; }
}
```

Also try this attribute `[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]` above your action. If it works then, you should be sending the antiforgery token with the post request.

Comment: i tried this with List<TempList> customers where TempList have CNIC in it but same issue

Comment: Did you try with [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken] attribute above the action?

Comment: yes i did as you told me

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
        public IActionResult SaveX(List<TempList> customers)
        {}

Comment: Is your action SaveX or Customers? Also what is the name of the controller and area(if you are using an area) ?

Comment: action name is Customers, Controller name ReconcileController, Area Admin

Comment: i have a breakpoint in Action Customers and the JSON post request is post

Comment: Have you specified the route to be exactly Customers with the route attribute above the Customers action or with the HttpPost attribute. If not try changing the url in the ajax request to admin/reconcile.

Comment: same not working any other solution?